# I want to choose specific thumbnail from post when I share Blogger post to my FB page.

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, blogger

FB sometimes offers me a couple of pics from the blog post as thumbnails, but other times just my blogger profile pic which I DO NOT want to use. I have trawled though questions but actually don't understand the answers.  Sorry.  I speak 3 foreign languages but html is not one of them.
Please could someone explain in simple language what to do?
I reiterate - I have in the past received a a choice of pics, and that was incredibly easy. I don't understand why this has stopped and now I suddenly need a degree in computer programming to do what Facebook offered without problem previously.

Comment: This is a programming site not affiliated with Facebook, if you aren't prepared for a programming answer, I suggest going to facebook.com/help/community or hiring a freelancer

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm, its not that complicated. Go to the below link and provide your URL. It will list all the meta tags it sees on the page. To keep it simple, meta tags are just few more extra lines of HTML used to describe your page.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Among the shown items, your should see a attribute named "og:image". OG image however have a set of rules to be followed like size and dimensions. The OG image is the image shown on the post. I would suggest that, you test your URL here before posting to Facebook. If it shows a image different that the one you wanted, try adding the below line inside the HEAD tag of your HTML.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<URL_TO_YOUR_IMAGE>" />
```

Replace the <URL_TO_YOUR_IMAGE> with the actual URL to the image that you want to appear in your post. I hope I have given simple enough instructions to follow. In your case, since you are using a blogger, I'm not sure how you can control the SEO tags (or meta tags) in the website. In wordpress, there is a SEO plugin which we use to set the SEO properly.